# Unknown graphics extension eps

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps

When I try to compile my tex file with an eps figure, I get the error message "Unknown graphics extension eps".
I don't understand why: I write `\usepackage{epstopdf}` in the preamble so there should be no problems. Moreover my pdflatex command is pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 %.tex

I paste below a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[ball]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\title{Title}    
\author{author name}     
\institute{University of XXX}

\date{}                   

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{"Fig/Figure9_1.eps"}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: try `Fig/Figure9_1` that is no quotes and no .eps

Comment: Why are you quoting the graphics name? Also, recent versions of pdflatex will automatically do a conversion of file.eps to file-eps-converted-to.pdf and insert that file so there is no need for the epstopdf package.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add my eps file (the system here allows you to upload only images in png, jpeg etc format) so I guess you are not able to replicate my error message